# PHP Add to cart session error

Tags: php, session

I'm testing out this simple shopping cart code and for some reason it doesn't seem to work. I've created 3 pages, 1st page contains:

```
<a href="add-to-cart.php?id=1">Item 1</a><br><br>
<a href="add-to-cart.php?id=2">Item 2</a><br><br>
<a href="add-to-cart.php?id=3">Item 3</a><br><br>
```

On the 2nd (add-to-cart.php) page:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(empty($_session['cart'])){
$_session['cart'] = array();
}

array_push($_session['cart'], $_GET['id']);
?>
<br><br>
Product is succesfully added to cart.
<a href="cart.php">View Cart Items</a>
```

Finally, on the 3rd (cart.php) page:

```
<?php 
session_start();

var_dump($_session['cart']);
?>
```

Instead of array, i get this error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: _session in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\add_to_cart\independent\compare.php on line 4
>
> NULL

Comment: And where is the file: `compare.php` in this file is the error?!

Comment: oops, sorry rizier123 its Notice: Undefined variable: _session in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\add_to_cart\independent\cart.php on line 4

Comment: Then my answer should work for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write session in capital letters like:

```
$_SESSION["cart"]
```

and not:

```
$_session["cart"]  //if you write it like this it's a normal array
```

So your code should look like this:

add-to-cart.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(empty($_SESSION['cart'])){
$_SESSION['cart'] = array();
}

array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $_GET['id']);
?>
<br><br>
Product is succesfully added to cart.
<a href="cart.php">View Cart Items</a>
```

cart.php:

```
<?php 

    session_start();
    var_dump($_SESSION['cart']);

?>
```

For more information see: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_SESSION` in uppercase. Variable names are case sensitive in PHP.